# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, checkboxlist

The `Exception`:

`Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.scytec.datamobile.vd.gui.android/com.scytec.datamobile.vd.gui.android.SelectedList}: java.lang.NullPointerException..`
I just  want to show checkbox list view and on every check it display "checked", simply but i don't know why this gives me an exception.

```
public class SelectedList extends Activity implements IObserver{

        private ListView machine_listview;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        ArrayList<String> arrayListofMachines;
        ArrayList<String> arrayListofMachineNumbers;
        Vector<MDCMachineStatus> machineStatus_vector;
        Handler handler;

        private static int oldPosition = 0;
        private Boolean firstClick = true;




        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.machinelistview);

            machine_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.machine_listview);
            machine_listview.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

            MachineStatusSingleton.Register(this);

            getData();

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SelectedList.this, R.layout.selectedlist,R.id.text1, arrayListofMachines);

            machine_listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            machine_listview.setSelection(oldPosition);


            CheckBox chk=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check);
            chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {

       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.xtra);
        if (arg1)
            Log.d("", "abul, checked") ;
        else
             Log.d("", "abul, not checked") ;

       }

            }
            );


            machine_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                        long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    oldPosition = position;
                    MachineStatusSingleton.setMachineNumber(arrayListofMachineNumbers.get(position));
                    SelectedList.this.finish();


                }

            });


            handler = new Handler(){
                public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {


                    machine_listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                };
            };






        }

        public void Update(ISubject arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy()
        {
            super.onDestroy();

            MachineStatusSingleton.Unregister(this);
        }

        private void getData(){
            machineStatus_vector = MachineStatusSingleton.GetData();
            arrayListofMachines = new ArrayList<String>();
            arrayListofMachineNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(MDCMachineStatus temp: machineStatus_vector){
                arrayListofMachines.add(temp.toString());
                arrayListofMachineNumbers.add(temp.getNumber());
            }

            Collections.sort(arrayListofMachines);
            Collections.sort(arrayListofMachineNumbers);

        }


        private void updateData(){
            getData();

            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            int index = machine_listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            View v = machine_listview.getChildAt(0);
            int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

            // ...

            // restore
            machine_listview.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: In your `LogCat`, take a look at the last couple of **red** lines which will give you the precise line number of the precise java file that's the reason for crash. It reads something like `Dalvik... NullPointerException caused by...`

Comment: sorry guys..  i have a problem in this:
        CheckBox chk=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check);
        chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {

   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
    TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.xtra);
    if (arg1)
        Log.d("", "abul, checked") ;
    else
         Log.d("", "abul, not checked") ;

   }

        }
        );

Comment: Is `R.id.xtra` defined in a layout?

Comment: Edit your Question with updated problem.

Comment: the only problem is in my checkbox function

Comment: chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We run our app very well and suddenly we encounter **NullPointerException** or **Unable to start activity** etc errors.

Basically **NullPointerException** or **Unable to start activity** occurs when there is issue in **onCreate()** method of our Activity.

**This occurs when :**

1. We change any xml values of layout related to this Activity
2. If we do not map xml UI's properly in our Acivity
3. Try to access UI which is in another layout file.

**Solution :**

1. First Cross check all the mapped elements
2. Give unique naming

Answer (score 10):

Directly after:
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.xtra);

... add this:
if (txt == null) { Log.w("", "TextView is null"); }

Assuming your null pointer exception doesn't occur until you select the checkbox, that sounds like the most likely issue. I've encountered the same when I forget that I removed the corresponding element from the XML layout, or if I got the ID wrong. Usually I wrap any actions upon an element returned by "findViewById" within a null check, to ensure that even if the retrieval fails, the app at least won't crash.

Comment: Don't ever do this.  You should not need to wrap all of your findViewByIds with a null check.  If the ID has been removed from the layout, your code should be changed to reflect this.

Comment: Agreed, updating the code to reflect the change is the best approach, by far. However, it's worth considering the potential impact if such a bug is missed -- without null checks, the app could end up unusable, crashing every time the user attempts to load a particular page, versus with null checks, the app will quite likely remain running with visual bugs. The decision of whether to use the null-checking pattern or not can be impacted by whether one is developing solo projects on the side, versus having full QA support to ensure full app stability.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're assigning to `chk`, and subsequently, `txt` by calling `findViewById` as you declare them. I had to declare them first, and then assign to them using `findViewById`.