# Android app seems to be crashing on launch on KitKat 4.4

Tags: java, android, xml, android-4.4-kitkat, inflate-exception

My app when installed on my relatively new Huawei running Oreo 8.0 is able to launch and run the app smoothly. The app also runs fine on the Nexus Emulator running Lollipop. However, on my other phone running KitKat 4.4 the app crashes when launched.

I think the problem occured when I added a default NavigationDrawerActivity.

> 09-05 14:05:57.285 30968-30968/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: com.example.a_phi.myapplication, PID: 30968
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.a_phi.myapplication/com.example.a_phi.myapplication.LoginActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
>   inflating class 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:711)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
>           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1958)
>           at com.example.a_phi.myapplication.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:44)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5340)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2228)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:711) 
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
>           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1958) 
>           at com.example.a_phi.myapplication.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:44) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5340) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2228) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:711) 
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.huawei.android.content.res.ResourcesEx.getThemeDrawable(ResourcesEx.java:655)
>           at com.huawei.android.content.res.ResourcesEx.loadDrawable(ResourcesEx.java:623)
>           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:616)
>           at android.view.View.(View.java:3573)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:470)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:179)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:175)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
>           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1958) 
>           at com.example.a_phi.myapplication.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:44) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5340) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2228) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:711) 
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**LoginActvity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {


    private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

    // UI references.
    private EditText mEmailView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private TextView mRegistrationScreen;
    private View mProgressView;
    private View mLoginFormView;
    public String id;

    @Override
    @TargetApi(19)
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_registration);
        // Set up the login form.
        mEmailView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);

        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
        mRegistrationScreen = findViewById(R.id.registerLink);
        mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String emailAddress = mEmailView.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString().trim();
                UserLoginTask callDOIB = new UserLoginTask();
                try {
                    String loginSuccessFail = callDOIB.execute(emailAddress, password).get();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(loginSuccessFail);
                        id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                        //JSONObject id = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        System.out.println("json object at LoginActivity id is "+id);
                        authoriseLogin(loginSuccessFail, id);
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (ExecutionException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        mRegistrationScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent loadRegistration = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(loadRegistration);
            }
        });
    }






    public void authoriseLogin(String authorise, String id){
        if (authorise.contains("id")) {
            System.out.println(" accessLRA.authoriseLogin login has been called");
            Session session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
            session.setId(id);
            Intent loadPersonal = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(loadPersonal);

            System.out.println("Login has been authorised");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Incorrect username or password");
        }
    }





    }
```

It is giving me an inflate exception when loading the layout file using `setContentView()`

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.a_phi.myapplication/com.example.a_phi.myapplication.LoginActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
>   inflating class

Comment: check your layout files. it may be that some of them are in layout-v21 folder. In that case, you're providing layout only for API level 21 and above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208023/unable-to-start-activity-componentinfo-java-lang-nullpointerexception)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments section, I was actually missing some other res -v21 folders which support API level 21 for Android KitKat. For some reason I didn't move them into my new project. It is working now, thank you.